# Creating classification features from wavelet transformed time series

Tags: r, machine-learning, time-series, classification, wavelet

I'm interested in using a wavelet transform, Haar for example, to create classification variables from time series data to use in logistic regression.

Simple example.  Let's say I'm trying to predict payment defaults and I have a person's monthly expense data and someone with consistent expenses is better than someone with increasing expenses in the the most recent 4 months.

If I have two sample borrowers:

Borrower A - Good - expensesA = c(100,110,95,105), default = 0

Borrower B - Bad - expensesB = c(75,100,150,200), default = 1

If I am using logistic regression, `glm()` in R, to create a classification model, and the R `wavelets` package `dwt()` function for a "haar" transform of the time series what are the appropriate features to extract from the `dwt()` object to use in `glm()`?

The truncated output for Borrower A is:

```
tr = dwt(expensesA, filter = "haar")
tr

An object of class "dwt"
Slot "W":
$W1
[,1]
[1,] 7.071068
[2,] 7.071068

$W2
[,1]
[1,]   -5


Slot "V":
$V1
[,1]
[1,] 148.4924
[2,] 141.4214

$V2
[,1]
[1,]  205


Slot "filter":
Filter Class: Daubechies
Name: HAAR
Length: 2
Level: 1
Wavelet Coefficients: 7.0711e-01 -7.0711e-01
Scaling Coefficients: 7.0711e-01 7.0711e

-01
```

I know `W`s are wavelet coefficients and the `V`s the scaling coefficients.

Do I need to use all four `W1` and `V1` values as variables to properly model this or is it okay to try just the `W1`s without `V1`s (or vice versa)?

Is it worthwhile to try only the single `W2` and `V2`s as variables?

Or is it better to try to use a clustering algortihm and label them based on clusters?

I know it of course also depends on the data, but I'm looking for a starting point regarding best practices.